# Thread safety of Java example using WeakReference

Tags: java, garbage-collection, thread-safety, weak-references

I am reading up on weak references in Java after seing a SO post and realising I didn't really know what they were.

The following code is from pp. 457, Chapter 17: "Garbage Collection and Memory" in "The Java Programming Language, Fourth Edition" by Arnold, Gosling and Holmes

```
import java.lang.ref.*;
import java.io.File;

class DataHandler {
    private File lastFile;        // last file read
    private WeakReference<byte[]> 
                         lastData;// last data (maybe)

    byte[] readFile(File file) {
        byte[] data;

        // check to see if we remember the data
        if file.equals(lastFile) {
            data = lastData.get();
            if (data != null)
                return data;
        }

        // don't remember it, read it in
        data = readBytesFromFile(file);
        lastFile = file;
        lastData= new WeakReference<byte[]>(data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand, just for the exercise of it, if this code is thread safe, with the part of code I am focusing on being the lines

```
data = lastData.get();
if (data != null)
    return data;
```

My thinking is as follows: "data" is thread confined and is set to reference the referent of the "lastData" WeakReference. This creates a strong reference to the referent, hence even if after the null check, all other strong references to the referent outside readFile's scope disappears (what's the correct term ?) and even assuming the referent is not softly reachable, the garbage collector is not allowed to clear the weak reference thereby making the referent finalizable, because there still is the local strong reference to it from data. Hence if data is not null in the `data != null` line, it can not be null when returned in the following line. Correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the example code is *not* thread safe, but for different reasons than using the weak reference:

The usage of the weak reference is fine, exactly for the reasoning you pointed out: The code creates a strong reference which is held in the `data` variable. Thus, the GC can't collect the bytes and thus also the `WeakReference` will stay intact; so using this code in a single threaded application should be safe. The problems come with multiple threads:

The access to the `file` and `lastData` fields is *not* synchronized, thus there is no guarantee that two Threads working with the `readFile(..)` method interact at all (which would be the unlikely "best" case). It is important to note that these fields must be accessed atomically, and if there is no other place where they are touched, the easiest fix would be to declare the `readFile` method synchronized. This would hurt performance rather badly, because the file reading would then happen inside the synchonized block, possibly causing bad contention.

Comment: Instead of synchronizing, I'd make a class that holds both file and data as final variables.  Then make a volatile reference to that class.  Then readFile can get a local reference to the class reference and use it through out the method.  Then update the instance field when done.

Comment: @Michael You are right, that's absolutely the way to go. I just wanted to point out the easiest way to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Once a reference has been assigned to the local `data` variable, the object is not eligible for garbage collection. It is [strongly reachable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability) because there is a reference to it in the thread's stack.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I overcomplicated those two lines. Just noting there is a strong reference to data is enough. Regarding strongly reachable: It sems there are two definitions in use. The one you reference: "An object is strongly reachable if it can be reached by some thread without traversing any reference objects." Secondly from the Java spec: "A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread" Are these equivalent and is there somewhere where the semantics of the second is rigorously defined ? I feel the spec isnt always precise

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking its not thread safe because the lastData and lastFile are not volatile.  It is possible for a second thread to see an old copy of these references.  It may not make much difference to your application.

Comment: I had assumed that discussion of threads comes into it is purely because of garbage collection and that `readFile` is not invoked across threads. You are correct of course.

Comment: I'd like to add that making the fields volatile would not help either, because it would allow to the file<->data association get out of sync so possibly wrong data is returned, because the file field was already updated while the reference was not.